# Modify axes in control chart RStudio

Tags: r, plot, axes, qcc

I would like to ask a help in modify axes in control chart in RStudio, by qcc package.

Generated a controlchart type EWMA, in the axes x, appear group, sequencially (that represents each observations), but I need insert an information about year (divide group into sequence of year). I tried using the command (axes), but doesn't work.

Which command or function it is possible to modify to achieve this?

Thank you very for help!

[image: Need change the group sequence in axes x to appear year of observation]

Yours faithfully

Guilherme

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ewma` function in`qcc` accepts a `labels` parameter: a character vector of labels for each group.
You could, for instance, do something like:

```
library(qcc)

data(pistonrings)
attach(pistonrings)
diameter <- qcc.groups(diameter, sample)

label_x <- as.character(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020/01/01"), length.out = 25, by = "day"))

q2 <-
   ewma(
    diameter[1:25, ],
    center = 0,
    lambda = 0.4,
    std.dev = 0.57,
    nsigmas = 3,
    add.stats = FALSE,
    labels = label_x
  )
```

And end up with a properly labelled x-axis in your EWMA plot:
[image]

Comment: Hi Paul, a question please, I need insert axes from 1990 to 2019, to appear in time step 5 year (1990,1995,2000.....), I tried used this syntax, but the vector size it is different of computeded in ewma. There is a way to achive it?

Comment: You can infer the number of x-axis ticks from the data in `q2`: `nrow(q2$data)` returns 25 in my example. So your `label` vector requires 25 elements.